# How to shrink the index page numbers in digits wise using perl

Tags: perl

In the Index file, we have primary, secondary and tertiary lines. In these lines we have page numbers with the ranges like:

```
nutrients in, 223-234
reproductive phase of, 115-116,
```

It should be

```
nutrients in, 223-34
reproductive phase of, 115-16,
```

It may be three digits or above... Could you please any one help me on this one.

Comment: Please provide an explanation

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: @Сухой27 it's way more complicated than that

Comment: @ysth perhaps there are too few test cases.

Comment: @Сухой27 here are some more: 123-24 should become 123-4.  1-1 and 123-234 should stay unchanged.

Comment: @dgw: Thanks for your comment. This is my first question about in asks this site. Try to compromise for my way of question posted in this site. Will do best in furture.

Comment: @dgw: I normally try not to answer questions like this, but it's actually a great excuse to show off some modern perl regex features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/(?=(\d(?:-|(?1))\d)(?![\d-]))(\d+)\d+-\K\2//ga
```

We start off finding a `digits-digits` string where the length of both sets of digits is the same, but without consuming any of it.  This involves a lookahead looking for a balanced sets of digits (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text? for a good explanation) and a negative lookahead to make sure no more digits follow (so we don't simplify `120-1234` into `120-34`) and also that it isn't something like 11-12-3 which we don't want to try to handle.  Note that it is ok for there to be extra digits before the balanced digits; this allows us to further simplify partially simplified ranges like `123-24`.

Once we've done that, we try to find as many digits from the first group as possible where there are at least some digits remaining and the digits in the second group start off the same (using the backreference `\2`).  `\K` is used to adjust where the substitution starts so that the replacement can remain empty.  `/a` is used to make `\d` just mean 0-9, not any other kinds of digits.

Comment: @dgw: Thanks for your comment. This is my first question about in asks this site. Try to compromise for my way of question posted in this site. Will do best in furture.